# Jenkins git pipeline plugin just stopped working on second repository checkout

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

So I used a Jenkins groovy script pipeline with some shell scripts to checkout a code repository. Then it runs some tests, packages the code then it used to switch to a new folder and checkout a second git repository.

So far so good, pretty simple really:

```
git url: 'git@gitlab:platform-automation.git', credentialsId: '12345678', branch: "${gitbranch}"
```

This used to (according to the job log) checkout a new branch using "git checkout -b feature/new-branch"

The code was refactored recently to allow it to report back to GitLab with some build status and now no longer checks out the branch:

```
 Cloning repository git@gitlab:platform-automation.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Package-for-Deployment/platform # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab:platform-automation.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials This key is used to access GitLab repositories
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab:platform-automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab:platform-automation.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab:platform-automation.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab:platform-automation.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials This key is used to access GitLab repositories
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab:platform-automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/feature/new-branch^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature/new-branch^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/feature/new-branch^{commit} # timeout=10

ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

Thats odd i thought lets go back to the old code using a git revert, same result.

So lets try removing the ${gitbranch} variable and using this:

```
git url: 'git@gitlab:platform-automation.git', credentialsId: '12345678', branch: 'develop'
```

Then on the next line add a line to a shell script that says this (which the plugin was doing anyway):

```
git checkout -b ${gitbranch}
```

Now the new branch gets checked out and the job carries on as expected.

Why does the Jenkins git pipeline plugin now have a problem checking out a branch using a variable?

Comment: "${gitbranch)"  - is this a typo? (ending paranthese)

should be "${gitbranch}"

Comment: Yes, typo corrected.

Comment: then we need some more info. was there a Jenkins Update? Did you clean up the workspace? Checked similar issues on  the Jenkins Git plugin page? maybe a bit more code, so that we can reproduce it fully on a local machine

Comment: No updates, workspace was not cleaned but the sub directory in which the second repository was to be cloned is deleted before each clone attempt. So the code is about 400 lines and after the changes was reverted back to exactly the same code which was working but it still fails using git revert.

Comment: Similar issues online have led me to adding a work around in a shell script that calls "git checkout -b ${gitbranch}" and then to get the git push working "git push -u origin HEAD:${gitbranch}" (wrapped in the sshagent plugin). Reference material included this https://caffinc.github.io/2015/11/github-pr-revision/

Comment: I don't really get your use case. If you have 2 different repos then:

     `dir(working_dir1) {
            git checkout repo
      }

      dir (working_dir2) {
            git checkout repo2
      } `

In case you want to do maintenance on branches from the same repo, well that is not was jenkins should do - so you have to use shell scripts and implement whatever logic you want to.

As a rule of thumb: different repos / branches have to go to different working dirs

Comment: They are in different folders as detailed in my initial question in the first paragraph.